# Toggle window size on window-top-border-doubleclick leaves to sel-screen?

Tags: abap, window-resize, sap-gui

We have a custom program, nothing special, a sel-screen, which opens a cockpit, where in the left side sits a tree in a panel , on the right side is the grid.

I do not know, whether this was ever done/tested/mentioned by anyone, but one of our users spotted this behaviour, because this person likes to toggle the window size by a doubleclick on the center of the top-border of the sapgui window.

Meaning, if the sap-gui-window was opened minimized, it will maximize and vice versa.
This causes a PAI-PBO cycle.
The sy-ucomm is empty.
The big "PAI <>" handler does not intercept an empty sy-ucomm, it deals only with those in the gui-status.

And yet, this resizing of the window causes the application to leave the cockpit and navigate back to the selection-screen.

Any clues ?

Comment: I would guess that you have some bug somewhere in your dynpro modules. But I can't say anything more without seeing any of your sourcecode. Can you try to create [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I would, but in ABAP You need to have at least 3 files. BUT I can post my PAI, if You like....

BTW: I added  when others. LEAVE TO SCREEN 0. And now it does not leave anymore, it behaves like intended. Maybe I copied a bad GUI status ?

Comment: Double clicking on the top of the window should only be a GUI action and should not go back to the ABAP program. Do you have the same issue with other programs? Have you tried search OSS for this error?

Comment: I searched, wherever I could. And this is my last resort